# update UILabel with the content of UICell from a different view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have an NSArray `tablePeople` which makes up my UITableView on my 1st View Controller `PeopleController`. I have a UILabel `personsName` on my second View Controller `PeopleDetailsController` which I want to update with the contents of `cell.textLabel.text` of each row in my TableView. I have this method but it's not working:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ((PeopleController *)segue.destinationViewController).delegate=self;
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toPeopleArticle"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;

        PeopleDetailsController *mdvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        mdvc.personsName.text = [self.tablePeople objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

I also have this code when the cell is selected:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toPeopleArticle" sender:indexPath];
}
```

I have to note that `PeopleDetailsController` is a modal view and `PeopleController` is a navigation view controller.

EDIT:
The text on the UILabel on the 2nd VC is just not being updated, it stays the same, that's the whole problem.

Comment: What's not working about it? Little more detail will help.

Comment: what does your code look like for the second controller?  When do you assign the label with the `personsName` property?

Comment: Well, I don't. In the code above it should say `mdvc.personsName.text` but even with this it doesn't change anything. personsName is a name for the UILabel itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following

```
PeopleDetailsController *mdvc = segue.destinationViewController;
mdvc.personsName.text = [self.tablePeople objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

to

```
PeopleDetailsController *mdvc = segue.destinationViewController;
mdvc.personsNameString = [self.tablePeople objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

where personsNameString is a property of type NSString in the PeopleDetailsController

Now in PeopleDetailsController viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear Function set the value of the label to the value of the property

```
mdvc.personsName.text = personsNameString;
```